# .htaccess change root folder and hide .html/.php extensions

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hide, root

I have changed the root folder using .htaccess but I also need hide the .html/.php extensions this is where i'm having trouble. I found alternatives to hide the extensions but its not as simple as I thought. Here is what I done so far>>>

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?cornellbond.co.uk$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/liveSite/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /liveSite/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?cornellbond.co.uk$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ liveSite/index.html [L]
```

This Works but when I add the following code to it everything stops working.

I then wanted to hide the .html/.php extensions I found this code on here SOF, so combined the two and all i got back is errors.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f       # if the requested URL is not a file that exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d       # and it isn't a directory that exists either
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f  # but when you put ".html" on the end it is a file that exists
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1\.html [QSA]         # then serve that file

</IfModule>
```

So my code looked like this all together which >>>

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?cornellbond.co.uk$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/liveSite/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /liveSite/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?cornellbond.co.uk$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ liveSite/index.html [L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f      
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d      
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f  
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1\.html [QSA]         

</IfModule>
```

If I could get a work around for this I would be most grateful. Did i say this all new to me and i'm still learning =P Thanks again

Comment: Hey mabarroso, I don't understand your answer, is it possible you can break it down for me to make it work thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to just hide extensions maybe look at this

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(php|html)$ /$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: hey Camel, thanks for the feedback, i will test it just now, thanks again ;)

Comment: *@camel, So I tried adding this line that you submitted,I had no errors which was great but no joy in removing the extension tags. It's a strange one, more help please.*